# HTML list <ul><li> type component in EXTJS 4

Tags: extjs4

Hi i need to create a list like :

- Coffee
- Milk

using EXTJS 4.
i think such a kind of thing can be created using Xtemplates. but i dont want to use any html. is there a component i can use ??

Please it is urgent!

Any pointers on how to go about it ?

Comment: Whether you use XTemplates or not, you will be generating HTML regardless.  So what exactly is your objection to XTemplate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need just a simple HTML list, I think you should use xtemplates just as you wrote.
But there are similar components in Extjs like grids or lists:

http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.7-gpl/examples/multiselect/multiselect-demo.html